# Neo4j flexible batch importer using Groovy

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, batch-processing

I wrote a Groovy script to create a flexible Neo4J batch importer as explained in this tutorial http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/flexible-neo4j-batch-import-with-groovy/. I wrote a code that seems OK but when I'm running it I get an error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.3!opencsv.jar]
I thought it was a problem with my code but then I tried to run the code from the example above posted on github with a CSV with the same format (author,title,date) and I get the same error.
Is it a problem with Groovy ?
Thank you for your help (probably Michael Hunger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy, the @Grab annotation checks if the dependencies can be resolved locally. If not it will hit a Maven repository to download.

My suspicion is that your machine does not have proper internet access. Maybe you have to configure a proxy, see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape for details.